# haskell: type mismatch error in recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have such a recursive function;

```
elim_all :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Mat El -> Mat El
elim_all c r1b r1e r2 m
     | r1b == r1e = elim_one c r1b r2 m
     | otherwise = elim_one c r1b r2 m : elim_all c (r1b+1) r1e r2 m
```

elim_one function is;

```
elim_one :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx ->  Mat El -> Mat El
elim_one c r1 r2 m = let val1 = ((m!!r1)!!c)
                         val2 = ((m!!r2)!!c)
                         row1 = (mulr r1 val2 m)!!r1
                         row2 = (mulr r2 val1 m)!!r2
                         nrow = zipWith (-) row1 row2
                         matr = if r1 == r2
                                     then m
                                     else replacer r1 nrow m
                      in matr
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘[El]’ with ‘Int’
    Expected type: [El]
      Actual type: Mat El
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘elim_one c r1b r2 m’
    In the expression:
      elim_one c r1b r2 m : elim_all c (r1b + 1) r1e r2 m
```

error still doesn't make sense to me. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What's the type of `elim_one`? What's `Mat El`?

Comment: type of elim_one is elim_one :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx ->  Mat El -> Mat El. Type of Mat El is [[]].

Comment: Then shouldn't the type of `elim_all` be `elem_all :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Mat El -> [Mat El]`?

Comment: Well, then the cons operator expects one element (a list), buy you supply a list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `elim_one` and `elim_all` compute something of type `Mat E1`. But whatever this might be, since

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

and for all types x, it holds that `x` is not the same as `[x]` you can never
relate the results of evaluation of `elim_one` and `elim_all`  with the `(:)` operator.

Answer (score 2):

So here is the line in question:

```
| otherwise = elim_one c r1b r2 m : elim_all c (r1b+1) r1e r2 m
```

Now you have said in your type signature that the result* of `elim_all` will be a `Mat El`, but in this line the result is a list (that is what the `(:)` operator forms).

Without knowing more about what the `Mat` type does, my best guess is that you need to wrap the output of this case in a Type Constructor of `Mat`.

---

* When the function is fully applied.